# Connect SSIS to online source with TLS1.2 fails

Tags: soap, ssis, sql-server-2016, tls1.2, afas-online

I try to make a connection via a web service task in SSIS to an AFAS getconnector. This worked till AFAS required a tls1.2 security. Now I can't get data out of AFAS.

I have SSIS 2016 installed with .net4.6.

I already searched the internet and tried to add a "script task" with the following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This didn't do the trick.

The error I get is:

> Error: 0xC002F304 at Employee, Web Service Task: An error occurred
>   with the following error message: 
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is:
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send..
>      at 
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection) 
>      at 
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser
>   taskVariableDispenser)
>      at 
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".

Does anyone know the solution for this issue?

Comment: I assume you're using the built in Web Service Task? If so I'll exclude my colourful opinions on this subject, as this is a problem I faced awhile ago. Effectively, after some time, i found that the Web Service task simply doesn't support TLS1.2; period. I had to end up converting my process that had a Web Service Task to a Script task, that *does* respect `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` as everything in contained in that script task. I realise that that isn't ideal, but it does seem to be a flaw in SSIS at this time.

Comment: yes, you're right. It's a built in web service task. If this doesn't work, it's maybe better/easier to export a csv from afas and process this by ssis.

Comment: If what you are receiving can just be a CSV, it would be extremely simple to do your extract in a script component (source) utilizing tls1.2

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Please have a look at the answer in [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f5502cc-a8ca-468d-ad55-a402376f2d42/question-on-setting-a-tls-12-value-within-a-ssis-package-when-connecting-to-vendors-url-using-a?forum=sqlintegrationservices). It describes two registry settings that force the use of TLS 1.2.